# Common table expressions with Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to learn the intuition behind CTE's in MySQL. What I really want to understand is how to create nested queries. For instance, I try running this code and I get a syntax error -

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT h.hacker_id, s.challenge_id, s.max_score FROM Hackers h
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT hacker_id, challenge_id, max(score) as max_score FROM Submissions 
    GROUP BY hacker_id, challenge_id
  ) s ON h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

What is wrong with this code? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...

Comment: This is an exercise from hackerrank, which I'm trying to use to learn sql. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contest-leaderboard/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: What is the continuation of that error message? The part following "near ..." is important for understanding what caused the error.

Comment: Also what does `SELECT VERSION();` return? It must be at least 8.0.1 to support CTE syntax.

Comment: Here's the rest of the error message - 'cte AS 
(
SELECT h.hacker_id, s.challenge_id, s.max_score FROM Hackers h
INNER J' at line 1

Comment: @Parma . . . You are using an old version of MySQL that doesn't support CTEs.  Use a newer version.

Comment: SELECT VERSION(); returns 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. I have been able to use CTE syntax for other problems.

Comment: Not on this instance you haven't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... Yes, appears that CTE is not supported due to the version. Not sure why I had success using CTE for other exercises.

Comment: @BillKarwin ... Yes, this was the issue / frustrating - hackerrank should provide consistency in the SQL versions across the exercises on their site

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Three ways

- Put a table alias on Submissions and then use it in all of the fields for the Submissions query.
- The Max() and group by on the Sumissions may be causing an error
- Put the Submissions query into a CTE before the final one and then use the sumissions one in the final query

With CteSubm as
(
Select ... from Submissions
),
CteJoin as
(
Select * from hckers h inner join ctesubm s on h.id = s.id
)
Select * from CTEjoin